# How to handle WCF Duplex timeout?

Tags: wcf, timeout, duplex

I've been searching the web for the last two days, but by no means, I can get my WCF Duplex service working. I've created a demo project which can be download from skydrive:

[WCFDuplexDemo.zip](http://cid-0e3c15c49b770682.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/WCFDuplexDemo.zip)

For the purpose of minimizing the number of possible error causes, I've decided to just return a short string in the callback handler because then, no max message size limits or whatsoever are exceeded. Normally, my WCF service would need some time (+15mins) to calculate a result and then return it to the client. To simulate this, I've put the executing thread to slepp for 12 minutes in DoWork().

The exception I get always mentions a possible problem with the `receiveTimeout`, which should be increased to prevent the problem. However, the `receiveTimeout` (and any other timeout I know) is set to three hours.

One more thing: I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and the problem also occurs when using WsDUalHttpBinding instead of netTcpBinding.

Answer (score 0):

Harrr! For those who encounter the same problem: I think, there is a bug in the .NET 3.5 implementation of WCF. I upgraded to .NET 4 and the problem is solved now.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the bug documentation or something?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here [Per-Session Services](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Instance-Management/Per-Session-Services/) and also check out the "Session Termination" section on opened page.

Hope this helps